# Lazarus: Disable console messages "WARNING: TGtk2WidgetSet.InvalidateRect refused invalidating"

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, lazarus

If program CudaText runs from terminal (on Ubuntu 14.04), then terminal is full of messages:

`WARNING: TGtk2WidgetSet.InvalidateRect refused invalidating during paint message`

How to disable them is the source? Maybe some {$define}?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a valid warning: if a repaint is requested while a control is painting you may trigger an endless loop. The painting code should only do the painting, nothing else. You should contact the author of CudaText to fix this, he is active in the Lazarus forum (http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org) and very cooperative.